# Silverstripe Image class field extension

Tags: image, field, silverstripe

Hi I need to have additional two fields inside of each Image class.
So right now I can edit the Image and I have fields like: 
 - title 
 - file name 
 - here I would like to have another one

Is there any chance to make that?
I've tried with different solutions but it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be rather simple. Just create an extension with your desired additional fields and an `updateCMSFields` method and apply it to "Image".

Example where I add a boolean flag to an image:

```
<?php
class ImageExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = array(
        'IsAnimation' => 'Boolean'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', CheckboxField::create(
            'IsAnimation', 
            _t('ImageExtension.IsAnimation', 'Is animation?')
        ));
    }
}
```

Then in your config file (`mysite/_config/config.yml`), add the following:

```
Image:
  extensions:
    - ImageExtension
```